# ATI Sapphire Radeon HD 5770 driver update crash

Tags: graphics-card, crash, amd-radeon, display-driver

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, with an ATI Sapphire Radeon HD 5770 card. The driver version is `2010.0504.2152.37420`, from 2010-05-04 (*their version numbering apparently corresponds with the release date*)

Now, I can't seem to update these drivers/CCC and other packages. If I pull the drivers from [**amd.com**](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_win8-64.aspx), the installation gets to a point where I lose display connectivity, (*which is expected when installing/updating the drivers*) but while display is lost my machine restarts, and I'm brought back to Windows with no functional display drivers. Thankfully I could roll them back to the 2010-05-04 version.

I haven't yet tried the ones from [**sapphiretech.com**](http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/?cid=1&gid=3&sgid=643&pid=305&psn=&lid=1&leg=0#) because I don't want to run in circles unnecessarily.

How do I correctly update the drivers/CCC for my system? I'm searching around for common/known issues with this driver version/hardware; can't find anything. Anyone know about problems with this?

Comment: Sorry; could the downvoter comment? Have I asked something inappropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Use the drivers from the card manufacturer rather than the chipset maker.  Some OEMs will make minor changes and so their driver is the one needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try to install the ccc again and when your machine restarts execute the installation file again and when it is successful installed restart your pc and now all should work.

mfg me