# Losing keyboard functionality; weird behavior

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

So, I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, and have a [Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wired-keyboard-600) that is only about 1 - 2 months old.

It has operated without issue since I purchased it, however, as of today I have begun experiencing intermittent functionality issues with it:

- I lose control of the keyboard, I cannot type with it regardless of the focused application.
- If I am typing when functionality is lost, it will continue reading the last key. (*for instance just 20 minutes ago, the comma key was what was pressed when it lost functionality, and whatever input control I focused with the mouse would only receive input of `,` repeatedly*)
- None of the mode keys (*Num/Caps/Scroll-lock*) respond on the keyboard.
- If I use the Windows on-screen keyboard, I can "type" as normal, and by toggling mode keys with the on-screen keyboard the physical keyboard responds (*the lights change state*)
- Unplugging/replugging the keyboard seems to fix it.

Now, I've been trying to reproduce the issue, but it's truly intermittent. I've been running Process Explorer, watching to see if any oddities come about. I've run a virus scan, no issues. I'm not using any special keyboard software/drivers; just defaults.

Now, the *only* thing that I have changed with my setup prior to this issue, was I attached a new monitor and attempted to update the display drivers. [The update failed](https://superuser.com/questions/619371/ati-sapphire-radeon-hd-5770-driver-update-crash) (*horribly, thanks ATI*) so I rolled them back and everything seemed to be fine. The new (*third*) monitor is functioning fine, and I've had no other issues. I attached the new monitor yesterday, attempted the driver update, dealt with the failure (*rolled back*), did a quick sanity check, and then had to leave, so I haven't really used the system until this morning.

I'm going a bit crazy here. Thankfully it hasn't failed while I've been typing thisssssssssssss (*just kidding*)

**Update** (*2013-08-26*)

It's been nearly a month and a half, and I *may* have found a pattern: *whenever I'm playing audio*.

It seems that whenever I fire up any music, fairly shortly thereafter, the keyboard will do as described above. Now, I'm fairly certain it's happened at least once *without* having started any audio, however, *with* audio it's nearly a certainty. I'll be checking my drivers and updating again as warrants.

Also, some additional details:

- I tried another USB keyboard; same issue.
- I tried a PS/2 keyboard; didn't get to test it long once I realized it lacked a <kbd>Win</kbd> key. (*which resulted in a prompt GTFO*)
- I've now tinkered with the audio drivers and used a different 3.5mm TRS port; no issues... **yet**.

Comment: Does the issue persist after a restart?

Comment: @terdon Yes, it does.

Comment: I know the monitor/display drivers mention seems like it should be unrelated, but I'm inclined to think it has something to do with it, as it's the only real change I've made to this system since I got the keyboard (*actually, in a long time*). Could something have happened when I performed the display driver rollback?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently with this keyboard. I'm not sure I remember it correctly and the steps below made it work, but at least it work with me.

- Uninstall the keyboard driver in Device manager
- Install driver download from Microsoft website
- Un-plug usb cable
- Plug-in to another usb port
- If it still does not work, un-plug, restart Windows, plug-in before Windows has loaded
- If none of the above works, manually install the keyboard driver

Comment: Thanks @Hardy; I'll update my question with more details. Unfortunately, I don't think it's actually the keyboard itself.